# High CPU load by system during slow memory allocation to a process

Tags: memory, centos6.4

I encounter an issue on one of my server (centOS 6.4 with kernel 2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64).

Let me explain it :

when I run 4 processes (let's call them p4), I saw that memory allocated to them increase very slowly (about 2 minutes to reach the max), in the same time I saw a load on the CPU by the system (about 60% of the CPU used by the system). Sometime CPU load is so high that the server is no more reachable and all applications running on it stop working.

The load end when the allocated memory reach her max for each processes.

I did some tests on another server (centos 5.8 with kernel 2.6.18-308.4.1.el5) and didn't observe this issue. The memory allocated to the same 4 processes (launched by me in the same way than previous test) increase very quickly (about 2 seconds average) and I didn't see any load on the CPU by the system.

Has someone encounter this ? Is this a known bug on centOS 6.4 ?

And how can I fix this issue ?

Many thanks for your help and don't hesitate if you need more informations.

Comment: You really need to give a full picture of things, what processes are you launching in your test, why memory is increasing till it hits the max?

Comment: Not sure what you want us to do with this aside from diagnose your ADD issue. My suggestion, use the other server. Feel free to upvote this.

Comment: more importantly: what mechanism is used to allocate memory? Is it possible that the processes induce lock/mutex contention for a shared resource? Do you see differing behavior when starting the processes one after the other?

Comment: You aren't using the current 6.4 kernel. Did you reboot after installing it? Or didn't install it at all?